# Integral $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have solved this problem $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\ dx$ by using series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ and $\ln(1-x)$. Can anyone solve this integration by suitable substitution.

Comment: Hint: $1/x dx= d\ln x$, $\ln a/b= \ln a- \ln b$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln \left( \frac{1+x}{1-x} \right) = 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now invert the order of the sum & integration ( and perform the integrations) 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^{1}  \frac{1}{x} \ln \left( \frac{1+x}{1-x} \right) dx  = 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} =   \frac{\pi^2}{4} .
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I agree ... I edited his question.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx$$
$$=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx$$

$$=-\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)|_0^1+\operatorname{Li}_2(x)|_0^1$$

$$=\frac12\zeta(2)+\zeta(2)=\frac32\zeta(2)$$

---

A different way is by setting $x=\frac{1-u}{1+u}$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\ dx=-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln u}{1-u^2}\ du$$

now use the series expansion for the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{x}[\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)]=2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k}}{2k+1}.$$

$$I=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2x^{2k}}{2k+1} dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(2k+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}.$$